# How to deploy Jenkins on AWS OpsWorks using Built-in Java App Layer?

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, aws-opsworks

I'm attempting to migrate my Jenkins installation from a custom AMI to Opsworks' Java/Tomcat layer. I rather like the sane defaults they set, and I'd like to keep the deployment as simple as possible.

This is operating on AWS Opsworks, using Amazon Linux 2014.09.

Following the directions for deploying a *.war here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/layers-java-deploy.html

I've created a simple git repository which contains the following:

```
jenkins-opsworks
├── deploy
│   └── before_migrate.rb
└── jenkins.war

1 directory, 2 files
```

`before_migrate.rb` contains the following snippet (provided by AWS)

```
::Dir.glob(::File.join(release_path, '*.war')) do |archive_file|
  execute "unzip_#{archive_file}" do
    command "unzip #{archive_file}"
    cwd release_path
  end
end
```

I've configured my Jenkins App to be of type Java, pointing to my github repo, and can verify that Opsworks does indeed deploy and run the `before_migrate.rb` hook, extracting the war file into `/srv/www/jenkins/current/`. Additionally, Catalina appears to have registered the Jenkins application, but I cannot see anything at `http://domain/jenkins`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Again-- I'm trying to stay as close to the Java layer without building a custom one, constraints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm trying to set this up myself.  I downloaded the latest .war from the site and I'm running OpenJDK 7 and Tomcat 7.  When I check on http://domain/jenkins/ and http://domain/ I can see the apache access log shows a 404.  Everything is stock settings.  Is there anything else in your `before_migrate.rb` that I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [Jonathan Weiss (@jweiss)](https://twitter.com/jweiss/status/573178467719782400), this actually works out of the box, and is accessible via http://domain/jenkins/. I was missing the trailing slash.